# Simple.OData.Client Insert object with its relations

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, odata

I am using Simple.OData.Client to consume ASP API. Every thing is OK. but I need to insert entity with it's relations entities

for example I have this entity

```
public class Offers
{
public int OfferID {get;set;}
public string OfferDescription{get;set;}

public ICollection<OfferAccessories> OfferAccessories{get;set;}
}
```

I need to insert collection of OfferAccessories by posting new Offer .. this happens automatically with normal API restful .. but with OData The list of OfferAccessories reaches the server empty
the Simple.OData.Client code

```
var client = new ODataClient(settings);
var result = await client.For<Offers>().Set(entity).InsertEntryAsync();
```

I hope I have explained the problem clearly